# Can data be transferred from an Access Database to TFS?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, tfs

Up until now we have been keeping a record of tasks and bugs in our projects in an Access Database. It has done the job so far but we've decided to look into the possibility of using Team Foundation Server instead as it is much better suited to our needs.

The data stored in our database is very similar to the fields used by TFS so that shouldn't be a problem. The issue is that currently there are about 2000 bugs and tasks in our Database that we would like to transfer across.

My research into the matter suggests that it isn't wise to enter data into TFS's database outside of TFS as it could cause issues, however entering the data manually would be very time consuming.

Is it possible to use SQL or something else to transfer the data using an application?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS is able to export and edit work item queries in MS Excel. You can add items there and export it (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd286627.aspx).

MS Access also can be exported to MS Excel (see http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/import-export-and-link-data-between-access-and-excel-HP001095095.aspx).

You can join both features to copy and paste all bugs.